# Accessing objects within objects in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom

How do I accesss the div the id 950 in the example below using javascript?

```
<ins>
<div>
<div>
<div id="950"></div>
</div>
</div>
</ins>
```

A simple getelementbyid doesn't work...

```
document.getElementById('950');
```

Comment: The `getElementById` call should work.  Please paste the entire document, including scripts.

Comment: it works, your code is not right in the other place

Comment: works fine for me in chrome...what browser are you getting this problem in??

Answer (score 2):

`getElementById` always returns the requested element, without regard nesting level. Something else must be going on here. For example, what is the purpose of the `ins` tag in your example?

Answer (score 1):

"id" can't begin with a number. See this: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name

Everything else is ok.

Comment: Are you sure? This example works fine for me in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/Sx2C8/

Comment: I am sure that another rule for naming the ID attribute is that it has to contain three or more characters but there is no mention of it in the link you provided (maybe it's part of the XHTML standard?)

Comment: @Justin Ethier: it may work on one browser engine, but cause issues with another. It has to do with how tolerable it is.

Comment: @Justin - I'm sure. See link in my answer. It can work but it shouldn't. :> Anyway, there is no other problem in code in question.

Comment: @silverstrike - I've never heard about that (ad at least three characters).

Comment: @Pawel: It seems that you are correct. Just gone through much of the spec for HTML4.0 and XHTML and couldn't find any mention of it - although I did find out that in HTML5 that restriction was removed: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/datatypes.html#common.data.id

Comment: Well, HTML 5 specification isn't finished yet. A browser may don't support this. Anyhow, we need more data about the problem from the author of question.

Answer (score 1):

The ID attribute should start with a letter. Perhapse that is what causing JS parser to return an error.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you are calling  `document.getElementById('950');` after dom elements are created.

Try shifting your code at the bottom of the page!!